# How to change the controller in Webots?

Tags: webots

[image]

I'm rather new at Webots.

How do I change the controller for a node to another controller code in a different location?

I'm having trouble changing the code for an e-puck. The edit controller always takes me back to the original code, and I can't save to another location.

I saved it as Epuck_Glider.c, but it won't take any coding changes, and whenever I try to reopen it via "edit controller" it always reopens and runs the original code.

Answer (score 0):

The controller can be changed from the Field editor (located just below the Scene Tree).
When you select the `EPuck.controller` field, the Field editor displays the currently used controller as well a "Select..." button to change it:

[image]

Note that Webots expects that a controller is located in a directory having the same name as the main controller source file. So, if you save your controller C file with a different name in the same directory as another controller, this new C controller won't be recognized.
[Here](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/the-standard-file-hierarchy-of-a-project#the-controllers-directory) you can find some documentation about the expected Webots project directory structure.

If you want to create a new controller, then the simplest option is to use the "New Robot Controller..." wizard. Since Webots R2022b this wizard is located in the "File / New" menu.

*Disclaimer: I am a part of the Webots development team.*